# Alert new value from user input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get an alert to display the value of whatever the user types into the password field. I can get the alert to display but not with the input value.

```js
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function newValue() {
  alert(password);
};
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login Card Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="username">
      Login <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="password">
      Password <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    </div>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password` is assigned before the `<input>`'s value changes, so it will always be blank. Instead, you need to assign it within the `onclick` so that it is assigned the updated value.

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function newValue() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  alert(password);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to retrieve the value of the password inside the callback:

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function newValue() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  alert(password);
};
```

Otherwise the value will be read immidiately on page load and will stay undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value after the user click on the button

```
alert(password.value);
```

and you need to declare `input` password as

```
var password = document.getElementById("password");
```

```js
var password = document.getElementById("password");

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function newValue() {
  alert(password.value);
};
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="username">
    Login <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="password">
    Password <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
  </div>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution on your JS FILE :)

```
var password = document.getElementById("password");

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function newValue() {
  alert(password.value);
};
```